# How can I get the coordinates of my second display with vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have this script where I'm getting the Horizonal and Vertical resolution of all the monitors, but so far I didn't find any way to know the coordinates of the monitor (I need to know if the second monitor connected to the computer is to the left or right of the main display).
Is there any code that I can run with vbscript that can get me this info?

```
    Set wmiObjSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf("Win32_VideoController")
    For Each obj In wmiObjSet
      WScript.Echo obj.CurrentHorizontalResolution
      WScript.Echo obj.CurrentVerticalResolution
    Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That information doesn't seem to exist in WMI unfortunately. It is in the registry, for example information about 2 monitors might be in 2 keys like this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{CDF19DFF-A10C-4CD9-ACD5-B830567D7476}\0000
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{CDF19DFF-A10C-4CD9-ACD5-B830567D7476}\0001
```

See the value for `Attach.RelativeX`, I think a value of zero indicates the primary monitor, a positive means that monitor is right of primary, and negative to the left.

So then the question is how you determine the CLSID of the video adapter... Which is a bit convoluted. I would perhaps select `PNPDeviceID` from `Win32_VideoController`, which looks like:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0126&SUBSYS_161C103C&REV_09\3&e89b380&0&10
```

Then use that to build a registry key path to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0126&SUBSYS_161C103C&REV_09\3&e89b380&0&10\Device Parameters
```

And get the value of `VideoID`, then use that to build a path to the `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` key.

**EDIT** A script to illustrate what I mean by the above

```
Option Explicit

Const HKLM = &H80000002
Const HKCC = &H80000005
Dim reg, clsid, mons, xval, i
Dim wmi, vc

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:")

'what if there is more than one instance of VideoController??
For Each vc In wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController")

  Call reg.GetStringValue( HKLM, _
      "SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\" & vc.PNPDeviceID & "\Device Parameters", _
      "VideoID", clsid)

  Call reg.EnumKey(HKCC,"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\" & clsid,mons)

  For i = LBound(mons) To UBound(mons)
    Call reg.GetDWORDValue(HKCC, _
        "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\" & clsid & "\" & mons(i), _
        "Attach.RelativeX", xval)

    If xval = 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "Monitor " & mons(i) & " appears to be the primary monitor"
    ElseIf xval < 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "Monitor " & mons(i) & " is left of primary"
    ElseIf xval > 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "Monitor " & mons(i) & " is right of primary"
    End If
  Next
Next
```